# Execute method in Sitecore Command Template will not trigger

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.1

It's my first shot at creating a command template. Basically I want the command to trigger when I create a content item based on a specific branch. I've tried to follow the guidelines in Sitecore's "Data Definition Cookbook", but I simply can't get it to work.

Here's exactly what I've done (in Sitecore 7.1):

I've created a Command Template like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Commands
{
    public class MyCommand : Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Command
    {
        public override void Execute(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CommandContext context)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I've registered it as a command in the Commands.config like this:

```
<command name="mynamespace:mycategory:mycommand" type="MyApp.Commands.MyCommand,MyApp"/>
```

In Sitecore I've created a command template called MyCommandTemplate based on the "/sitecore/templates/System/Branches/Command Template" template and set the Command field to:

```
mynamespace:mycategory:mycommand(id=$ParentID)
```

Additionally I've created a data template called MyTemplate and in "__Standard Values" I've added MyCommandTemplate to Insert Options.

For MyTemplate I've created a branch called MyBranch based on the "/sitecore/templates/System/Branches/Branch" branch template, and on the branch's $name sub item I've checked that it does indeed have MyCommandTemplate set in Insert Options.

However, when I create a content item based on MyBranch, then the Execute method in MyCommand is not triggered (code is not run and I can't hit it with debugger in Visual Studio).

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if command template works on branch level, to test if your code works, try adding an item based on 'MyTemplate' data template, and see if your code runs.

If command template does not work on branch level, i suggest you add some code to your command template class which creates the items needed when the user creates any item based on 'MyTemplate' data template

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it, but the command is still not triggered :(

Comment: Just found out that when I create a content item based on MyBranch, and then right-click on the content item og choose Insert, then I can select the command. And when I do that the code is triggered. But it isn't really the way I would expect it to work, since it then requires two actions by the user to create the content item structure.

Comment: I would suggest you don't use branch template, and in your Command template class you can create items structure, see this example : http://pentialized.dk/2009/05/15/command-templates-the-forgotten-feature-of-sitecore-6/
Then when user insert item (choose command), your code gets triggered and create the items structure you want with one action from user

Comment: Thanks, I think that your initial answer combined with these comments constitutes a viable solution.